# Change OpenLayers3 vector to edit via button

Tags: openlayers-3

I have two vector polygons layers (ol3.2) and want users to switch between drawing and interacting with them via a button. I’d like the select and modify methods to work only for the active polygon layer. The [documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html?unstable=true) implies that the 'layers' option can be used to limit which layers can be selected, but I am not quite clear of the syntax. With task.myvector1 as the name of an ol.layer.Vector, I currently have:

```
select = new ol.interaction.Select({ 
    layers: [ task.myvector1 ] 
});
modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
  features: select.getFeatures()
});
```

But that does not successfully allow a selection, whereas when the option is removed select-and-modify works well, albeit for all layers.

Assuming this is just a syntax glitch, is there then a way to update the layers option in 'select', after a button click event, to switch the selectable layer to, for example, task.myvector2?

Comment: Make sure that `task.myvector1` is a vector layer (i.e. `ol.layer.Vector` or a subclass of it). Then everything should work.

Comment: @ahocevar Yes, task.myvector1 is ol.Layer.Vector and it can be selected when the "layers: [ task.myvector1 ]" is commented out, but cannot be selected when it is present (no console error, just no selection).

Comment: Hard to say then without seeing more of your code. All I can say is that your usage of the API looks correct in this case.